# Install 64bit OS on computer running 32bit OS if the computer supposedly can run 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-10-preview

My dad has a laptop running Windows 7 32bit, and wants me to install Windows 10 TP 64bit on it. He insists that the laptop can run a 64bit OS and he cannot use a 32bit OS because of the programs he wants to use.

I attempted to run the installer from a bootable USB I set up when installing on another laptop (which worked fine) but received an error message relating to the difference of 32bit and 64bit.

First question is can I install the 64bit OS and will it run?
Second question is how can I install it?

Error message:

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. 
Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit)
or x64 (64-bit) version on the program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

**UPDATE:** The Computer is confirmed to be able to run a 64bit OS - Kudos to megamorf

Comment: What was the **exact** error message? "I got an error" isn't helpful; "when I did specific-thing-X, I got an error saying 'foobar baz 0x12345678' and the system stopped responding to input" is helpful. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling edited the post just now

Comment: Much better now. I don't have an answer for you, but this should give someone who does much more to go on.

Comment: Are you sure you booted from the bootable USB? Obviously, running the installer from it without booting from it won't work.

Comment: Its not possible to install a 64-bit version of Windows from within Windows boot to the installation disk in order to format your HDD and install Windows.

Comment: Where in the install process do you see that error message: during boot time, or in Windows setup?

Comment: In the error message, "this file" may refer to the software he's trying to run in Win 10 or to a driver.  Also, it could potentially be a compatibility issue with Win 10, itself, not a 32 vs 64 bit issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can follow Microsofts instructions to check if your processor is 64-bit ready:

> To run a 64-bit version of Windows, your computer must have a 64-bit-capable processor. To find out if your processor is 64-bit-capable in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, do the following:
>
> Open Performance Information and Tools by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type Performance Information and Tools, and then, in the list of results, click Performance Information and Tools.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> ```
>    In Windows 7, click View and print detailed performance and system information.
>
>    In Windows Vista, click View and print details.
> ```
>
> In the System section, you can see what type of operating system you're currently running under System type, and whether or not you can run a 64-bit version of Windows under 64-bit capable. (If your computer is already running a 64-bit version of Windows, you won't see the 64-bit capable listing.)

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7

If you just download all the latest Windows 7 Updates you'll install the Windows 10 Upgrade checker update (http://www.howtogeek.com/218880/windows-10-is-almost-here-heres-what-you-need-to-know) that also checks if your PC is able to run Windows 10.

Also, I wouldn't recommend installing the technical preview now that the official (and free) release of Windows 10 is just 1.5 months away since you'll be required to do a fresh install of Windows 10 if you are running the TP.

Comment: The computer is 64bit capable.
Also multiple sources state that users of the Tech Preview can upgrade straight from TP to the RTM Version without a clean install. 
One source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/can-users-of-the-windows-10-technical-preview/4eb109e8-acad-4d77-b4d9-0edfeb8dc9f1

This answers my first question, but not my second.

Comment: Your second question has already been answered in the comments - boot from the install disk.

Comment: @Dave Seeing as after I commented that I edited the original question crediting megamorf for the first question.
Also there is no way to credit a comment as a correct answer